# Colocar os campos de um form Django na mesma linha

Tags: html, django, django-templates

Tenho um form no Django e no template exibo os campos para serem preenchidos:

```
<div id="interval" class="form-inline form-group">
                    <div class="two wide field">
                        {% for price in prices %}
                        <div class="fields">
                            <div class="ten wide field">
                                <label>Preço</label>
                                {{ price.price }}
                            </div>

                           <div class="ten wide field">
                                <label>Inicio</label>
                                {{ price.start_time }}
                           </div>
                            <div class="ten wide field">
                                <label>Final</label>
                                {{ price.end_time }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Porém está ficando um campo embaixo do outro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que os campos aparecam lado a lado,  `Inicio | Fim | Preco`, já tentei mexer nas divs mas não estou conseguindo, é algo no Django?

Comment: Cade o CSS ? Sem ele nao da para te responder de forma concreta.

Comment: Não é uma questão de django e sim css, dica: use [esse pacote para forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só removi as `div` que estavam dentro dos `inputs`

```html
<div id="interval" class="form-inline">
    <div class="two wide field">
        {% for price in prices %}
        <label>Preço</label>
        {{ price.price }}
        <label>Inicio</label>
        {{ price.start_time }}
        <label>Final</label>
        {{ price.end_time }}
        </div>
</div>
```